# Redirect doesn't work in Spring with Apache Tiles

Tags: java, spring, apache, servlets, tiles

I've to perform a redirect in Spring MVC from one controller to another but it doesn't work! The page and the url doesn't change BUT in network I see that the call is performed and the response is correct!
Normally I write a method that return a String and the return looks like this:

```
return "redirect:/methodOfOtherController";
```

or, instead, method return a ModelAndView and code like this:

```
return a new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("methodOfOtherController"));
```

or: 
return a new ModelAndView("redirect:/methodOfOtherController");

I've tried, also, with HttpServletResponse like this:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "methodOfOtherController");
```

but no way...so I've added

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", request.getContextPath() + "methodOfOtherController");
```

The path of redirection is correct but isn't the issue...I've same issue if I try to redirect to google site!
The jsp page doesn't change...